# Keep Variables Created by Macro

Tags: sas

I have the following code where I rename column names; I would like to keep only the variables created by the macro. I do realize I can drop the old variables but am curious if there is a keep option I can place inside the macro.

So for example, in the datastep, I would want to keep only the variable that start with '%transform_this(JUNE19)';

Thanks!

```
 %macro transform_this(x);
 &x._Actual=input(Current_Month, 9.0);
 &x._Actual_Per_Unit = input(B, 9.);
 &x._Budget=input(C, 9.);
 &x._Budget_Per_Unit=input(D, 9.);
 &x._Variance=input(E, 9.);
 &x._Prior_Year_Act=input(G, 9.);
 Account_Number=input(H, 9.);
 Account_Description=put(I, 35.);
 &x._YTD_Actual=input(Year_to_Date, 9.);
 &x._YTD_Actual_Per_Unit=input(L, 9.);
 %mend transform_this;

 data June_53410_v1;
 set June_53410;
 %transform_this(JUNE19);
 if Account_Description='Account Description' then DELETE; 
 Drop Current_Month B C D E G H I Year_to_Date L M N;
 run;
```

Comment: When I see a process like this, I suspect a TRANSPOSE was likely needed somewhere so the full solution is dynamic each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am curious if there is a keep option I can place inside the macro.

You can definitely use `keep` in your macro:

```
%macro transform_this(x);
    keep &x._Actual &x._Actual_Per_Unit
         &x._Budget &x._Budget_Per_Unit
         &x._Variance &x._Prior_Year_Act
        Account_Number Account_Description 
        &x._YTD_Actual &x._YTD_Actual_Per_Unit
    ;

    &x._Actual=input(Current_Month, 9.0);
    /* ...and the rest of your code */
%mend transform_this;
```

Any reason you thought you can't?

Answer (score 3):

```
keep June19_: Account_:;
```

This keeps all variables starting with June19_ and Account_ which are the ones you need evidently.

Answer (score 2):

Add two sentinel variables to the data step, one before the macro call and one after.  Use the double dash `--` variable name list construct in a `keep` statement and drop the sentinels in the data step output data set specifier `drop=` option.

```
data want (drop=sentinel1 sentinel2); /* remove sentinels */
  set have;
  retain sentinel1 0;
  %myMacro (…)
  retain sentinel2 0;
  … 
  keep sentinel1--sentinel2;  * keep all variables created by code between sentinel declarations;
run;
```

> [**Name Range Lists**](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1cr0027z6qx4an1maoh0fyizqtt)
>
> Name range lists rely on the order of variable definition, as shown in
>   the following table:
>
> *Name Range Lists*
>
> `Variable List`  Included Variables
>   `x -- a`        all variables in order of variable definition, from
>   variable x to variable a inclusive
>   `x -NUMERIC- a` all numeric variables from variable x to variable a inclusive
>   `x -CHARACTER- a` all character variables from variable x to variable a inclusive
>
> **Note:** Notice that name range lists use a double hyphen ( `--` ) to designate
>   the range between variables, and numbered range lists use a single
>   hyphen to designate the range.

Comment: This seems legit, but I couldn't find where this is documented in the official reference. Do you have a link?